# xslt:How to use meta tag?

Tags: xslt, internet-explorer-10

How do we include a meta tag like `"<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>"`
in xslt? Or else how do we check IE compatibility for IE10 and for others.

My below code in Web config file works well for IE10, now i`m supposed to include the same in xslt,or alternate code that should work for IE10.
Code:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE9" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about client-side XSLT which transforms XML to HTML and in the HTML result you want to include the `meta` then simply put it in the template outputting the `html` `head` element e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"/>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

..
```

Comment: martin: Thanks for the answer. But it`s not yet compatible. Anything extra do i need to add?

Comment: Your question so far is about outputting the `meta` tag in general. That should be done as suggested. If you are talking about one particular compatibility feature then tell us in detail what you want to achieve and in what way it fails. I am afraid with your question showing `IE=edge` in the text and `IE=EmulateIE9` in the config except it is not clear which setting you want.

Comment: Martin: My code in my post,I have added this in web.config file,the same I need to add in a xsl file. So that it should work for IE10. Extjs 3.0 not working in IE10.

Comment: Well if you want the same as in the config you need `IE=EmulateIE9` instead of `IE=edge` obviously. I will edit my suggestion.